# Can we write the definition of domain as below?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The definition of a domain in my book is as follows :

$Dom(f) ={[ x \in E | \exists! y \in F   s.t. y =f(x)}] $

Can I write it as :

$Dom(f) ={[ x \in E | f(x) \in F}] $?

Comment: Your definition does not take into account the fact that $f$ is well-defined, while your book’s does . If you want to restate their definition you might have to take this into account.

Comment: what do you mean by" f is well defined "?

Comment: A function is well defined on a set if each “input” yields a unique “output”.  For an example of a function that is *not* well defined: $g(0)=1$ and $g(0)=2$. So, when your book says $$\exists ! y\in F$$ they are making sure that cases like the function $g$ don’t happen. $0$ has room in your definition while it does not in the books definition.

Comment: Your suggestion omits the information supplied by that exclamation mark.

Comment: In set theory, the *domain* is defined for a *relation* in general: $\text {Dom}(R) = \{ x \mid \exists y ((x,y) \in R) \}$. A *function* is a particular kind of relation: thus, the general definition applies.